# Elasticsearch ngram tokenizer returns all results regardless of query input

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-6

I am trying to build a query to search for records in the following format: `TR000002_1_2020`.

Users should be able to search for results the following ways:

`TR000002` or `2_1_2020` or `TR000002_1_2020` or `2020`. I figured an ngram tokenization query would be best suited for my needs. I am using Elasticsearch 6.8 so I cannot use the built in Search-As-You-Type introduced in E7.

Here's my implementation I followed from docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html). The only thing I modified was EdgeNGram -> NGram as the user can search from any point of the text.

My Analysis block looks like this:

```
.Analysis(a => a
    .Analyzers(aa => aa
        .Custom("autocomplete", ca => ca
            .Tokenizer("autocomplete")
            .Filters(new string[] {
                "lowercase"
            })
        )
        .Custom("autocomplete_search", ca => ca
            .Tokenizer("lowercase")
        )
    )
    .Tokenizers(t => t
        .NGram("autocomplete", e => e
            .MinGram(2)
            .MaxGram(16)
            .TokenChars(new TokenChar[] {
                TokenChar.Letter,
                TokenChar.Digit,
                TokenChar.Punctuation,
                TokenChar.Symbol
            })
        )
    )
)
```

Then in my mapping I define:

```
.Text(t => t
    .Name(tr => tr.TestRecordId)
    .Analyzer("autocomplete")
    .SearchAnalyzer("autocomplete_search")
)
```

When I search for `TR000002`, my query returns all results instead of just the records that contain those specific characters. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better tokenizer for this specific use case? Thanks!

EDIT: Here's a sample of what is returned:

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 27,
    "max_score" : 0.105360515,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test-records-development-09-09-2020-02-00-00",
        "_type" : "testrecorddto",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.105360515,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 3,
          "testRecordId" : "TR000002_1_2020",
          "type" : 0,
          "typeName" : "TIDCo60",
          "missionId" : 1,
          "mission" : {
            "missionId" : 1,
            "name" : "[REDACTED]",
            "mRPLUsername" : "[REDACTED]",
            "missionRadiationPartsLead" : {
              "username" : "[REDACTED]",
              "displayName" : "[REDACTED]"
            },
            "missionInstruments" : [
              {
                "missionId" : 1,
                "instrumentId" : 1,
                "cognizantEngineerUsername" : "[REDACTED]",
                "instrument" : {
                  "intstrumentId" : 1,
                  "name" : "Instrument"
                },
                "cognizantEngineer" : {
                  "username" : "[REDACTED]",
                  "displayName" : "[REDACTED]"
                }
              },
              {
                "missionId" : 1,
                "instrumentId" : 2,
                "instrument" : {
                  "intstrumentId" : 2,
                  "name" : "Instrument 2"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "procurementPartId" : 2,
          "procurementPart" : {
            "procurementPartId" : 2,
            "partNumber" : "procurement part",
            "part" : {
              "partId" : 1,
              "manufacturer" : "Texas Instruments",
              "genericPartNumber" : "123",
              "description" : "description",
              "partTechnology" : "Part Tech"
            }
          },
          "testStatusId" : 12,
          "testStatus" : {
            "testStatusId" : 12,
            "name" : "Complete: Postponed Until Further Notice"
          },
          "discriminator" : "SingleEventEffectsRecord",
          "testRecordServiceOrders" : [
            {
              "testRecordId" : 3,
              "serviceOrderId" : 9,
              "serviceOrder" : {
                "serviceOrderId" : 9,
                "serviceOrderNumber" : "105702"
              }
            }
          ],
          "rtdbFiles" : [ ],
          "personnelGroups" : [
            {
              "personnelGroupUsers" : [ ]
            },
            {
              "personnelGroupUsers" : [ ]
            }
          ],
          "testRecordTestSubTypes" : [ ],
          "testRecordTestFacilityConditions" : [ ],
          "testRecordFollowers" : [ ],
          "isDeleted" : false,
          "sEETestRates" : [ ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test-records-development-09-09-2020-02-00-00",
        "_type" : "testrecorddto",
        "_id" : "11",
        "_score" : 0.105360515,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 11,
          "testRecordId" : "TR000011_1_2020",
          "type" : 0,
          "typeName" : "TIDCo60",
          "missionId" : 1,
          "mission" : {
            "missionId" : 1,
            "name" : "[REDACTED]",
            "mRPLUsername" : "[REDACTED]",
            "missionRadiationPartsLead" : {
              "username" : "[REDACTED]",
              "displayName" : "[REDACTED]"
            },
            "missionInstruments" : [
              {
                "missionId" : 1,
                "instrumentId" : 1,
                "cognizantEngineerUsername" : "[REDACTED]",
                "instrument" : {
                  "intstrumentId" : 1,
                  "name" : "Instrument"
                },
                "cognizantEngineer" : {
                  "username" : "[REDACTED]",
                  "displayName" : "[REDACTED]"
                }
              },
              {
                "missionId" : 1,
                "instrumentId" : 2,
                "instrument" : {
                  "intstrumentId" : 2,
                  "name" : "Instrument 2"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "procurementPartId" : 2,
          "procurementPart" : {
            "procurementPartId" : 2,
            "partNumber" : "procurement part",
            "part" : {
              "partId" : 1,
              "manufacturer" : "Texas Instruments",
              "genericPartNumber" : "123",
              "description" : "description",
              "partTechnology" : "Part Tech"
            }
          },
          "testStatusId" : 1,
          "testStatus" : {
            "testStatusId" : 1,
            "name" : "Active"
          },
          "discriminator" : "TotalIonizingDoseRecord",
          "creatorUsername" : "[REDACTED]",
          "creator" : {
            "username" : "[REDACTED]",
            "displayName" : "[REDACTED]"
          },
          "testRecordServiceOrders" : [ ],
          "partLDC" : "12",
          "waferLot" : "1",
          "rtdbFiles" : [ ],
          "personnelGroups" : [
            {
              "personnelGroupUsers" : [ ]
            }
          ],
          "testRecordTestSubTypes" : [ ],
          "testRecordTestFacilityConditions" : [ ],
          "testRecordFollowers" : [ ],
          "isDeleted" : false,
          "testStartDate" : "2020-07-30T00:00:00",
          "actualCompletionDate" : "2020-07-31T00:00:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test-records-development-09-09-2020-02-00-00",
        "_type" : "testrecorddto",
        "_id" : "17",
        "_score" : 0.105360515,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 17,
          "testRecordId" : "TR000017_1_2020",
          "type" : 0,
          "typeName" : "TIDCo60",
          "missionId" : 1,
          "mission" : {
            "missionId" : 1,
            "name" : "[REDACTED]",
            "mRPLUsername" : "[REDACTED]",
            "missionRadiationPartsLead" : {
              "username" : "[REDACTED]",
              "displayName" : "[REDACTED]"
            },
            "missionInstruments" : [
              {
                "missionId" : 1,
                "instrumentId" : 1,
                "cognizantEngineerUsername" : "[REDACTED]",
                "instrument" : {
                  "intstrumentId" : 1,
                  "name" : "Instrument"
                },
                "cognizantEngineer" : {
                  "username" : "lewallen",
                  "displayName" : "[REDACTED]"
                }
              },
              {
                "missionId" : 1,
                "instrumentId" : 2,
                "instrument" : {
                  "intstrumentId" : 2,
                  "name" : "Instrument 2"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "procurementPartId" : 2,
          "procurementPart" : {
            "procurementPartId" : 2,
            "partNumber" : "procurement part",
            "part" : {
              "partId" : 1,
              "manufacturer" : "Texas Instruments",
              "genericPartNumber" : "123",
              "description" : "description",
              "partTechnology" : "Part Tech"
            }
          },
          "testStatusId" : 1,
          "testStatus" : {
            "testStatusId" : 1,
            "name" : "Active"
          },
          "discriminator" : "TotalIonizingDoseRecord",
          "creatorUsername" : "[REDACTED]",
          "creator" : {
            "username" : "[REDACTED]",
            "displayName" : "[REDACTED]"
          },
          "testRecordServiceOrders" : [ ],
          "rtdbFiles" : [ ],
          "personnelGroups" : [
            {
              "personnelGroupUsers" : [ ]
            }
          ],
          "testRecordTestSubTypes" : [ ],
          "testRecordTestFacilityConditions" : [ ],
          "testRecordFollowers" : [ ],
          "isDeleted" : false
        }
      },
```

Also here's what shows for `mapping`:

```
"testRecordId" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
  "search_analyzer" : "autocomplete_search"
},
```

I guess I should also mention, I've been testing this query in the console like so:

```
GET test-records-development/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "testRecordId": {
        "query": "TR000002_1_2020"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT 2: Added API response from index `_settings` endpoint:

```
{
  "test-records-development-09-09-2020-02-00-00" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "provided_name" : "test-records-development-09-09-2020-02-00-00",
        "creation_date" : "1599617013874",
        "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "autocomplete" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "autocomplete"
            },
            "autocomplete_search" : {
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "lowercase"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer" : {
            "autocomplete" : {
              "token_chars" : [
                "letter",
                "digit",
                "punctuation",
                "symbol"
              ],
              "min_gram" : "2",
              "type" : "ngram",
              "max_gram" : "16"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "0",
        "uuid" : "FSeCa0YwRCOJVbjfxYGkig",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "6080199"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific when you say returns all the results, you should provide some sample docs and expected docs and current docs in your result, I've used this query several times and it works.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja added an edit to show you a sample of the data that's returned (3 of the 27). The `testRecordId` property is what is important. I've also added the `index/_mapping` GET to show that it is using the analyzers. What else can I provide you with to help? Thanks! EDIT: also added how I've been testing the results using the kibana console

Comment: thanks and it much clear, I know why this issue is happening but to confirm, I need to see your index setting in JSON format, could you please use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html setting API to provide that?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I've added an edit to show the `_settings` response if that helps. Thanks so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't have the analyzer setting access in JSON format,I can't confirm it but most probably issue is with your search analyzer `autocomplete_search` which is creating search time tokens which are matching the index time tokens.

For example: you are searching for `TR000002_1_2020` and if it creates `2020` as a token and for document containing `TR000011_1_2020` also creates a `2020` token than  your query will match it.

You can use the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to check the generated tokens based on a analyzer and as mentioned earlier mostly there is some tokens which are matching as shown above.

Comment: So yes, this is exactly what's happening according to the `analyze` API! Given your experience what is a method you tend to use for a given search scenario like this? Would I have to result to wildcard? Using wildcard was my first attempt but I had some issues with wildcard queries being case sensitive since it's on the keyword

Comment: @JordanLewallen also please ping me as soon as you have the link of new question and I would provide you working solution as fast as I can :)

Comment: good point, created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63807587/6480913 marked this one as correct! Appreciate the help so far