# How to perform partial word searches on a text input with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-6

I have a query to search for records in the following format: `TR000002_1_2020`.

Users should be able to search for results the following ways:

`TR000002` or `2_1_2020` or `TR000002_1_2020` or `2020`. I am using Elasticsearch 6.8 so I cannot use the built in Search-As-You-Type introduced in E7. Thus, I figured either `wildcard` searches or `ngram` may best suit what I needed. Here were my two approaches and why they did not work.

1. Wildcard

Property mapping:

```
.Text(t => t
    .Name(tr => tr.TestRecordId)
)
```

Query:

```
m => m.Wildcard(w => w
    .Field(tr => tr.TestRecordId)
    .Value($"*{form.TestRecordId}*")
),
```

This works but it is case-sensitive so if the user searches with `tr000002_1_2020`, then no results would return (since the `t` and `r` are lowercased in the query)

2. ngram (search as you type equivalent)

Create a custom ngram analyzer

```
.Analysis(a => a
    .Analyzers(aa => aa
        .Custom("autocomplete", ca => ca
            .Tokenizer("autocomplete")
            .Filters(new string[] {
                "lowercase"
            })
        )
        .Custom("autocomplete_search", ca => ca
            .Tokenizer("lowercase")
        )
    )
    .Tokenizers(t => t
        .NGram("autocomplete", e => e
            .MinGram(2)
            .MaxGram(16)
            .TokenChars(new TokenChar[] {
                TokenChar.Letter,
                TokenChar.Digit,
                TokenChar.Punctuation,
                TokenChar.Symbol
            })
        )
    )
)
```

Property Mapping

```
.Text(t => t
    .Name(tr => tr.TestRecordId)
    .Analyzer("autocomplete")
    .SearchAnalyzer("autocomplete_search")
)
```

Query

```
m => m.Match(m => m
    .Query(form.TestRecordId)
),
```

As described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63804455/6480913), this does not work since the tokenizer splits the characters up in to elements like `20` and `02` and `2020`, so as a result my queries returned all documents in my index that contained 2020 such as `TR000002_1_2020` and `TR000008_1_2020` and `TR000003_6_2020`.

What's the best utilization of Elasticsearch to allow my desired search behavior? I've seen `query string` used as well. Thanks!

Comment: Is there some generic pattern to the format `TR000002_1_2020` i.e. one that could be discerned from a regular expression?

Comment: @RussCam hmm so the only part of that string that would be consistent is the `TR`. The `000002` would increment (it's called the test record number), the `_1_` is the mission number so that changes and `2020` is the year so that would obviously increment as well

Comment: Ok, so a pattern like `TR\d+_\d+_\d+` would work? I'm thinking that a Pattern tokenizer in conjunction with shingles and lowercase token filters could be an approach that works

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple way to address your requirements ( I hope ).

1. we use a pattern replace char filter to remove the fixed part of the reference ( TR000... )
2. we use a split tokenizer to split the reference on the "_" character
3. we use a matchPhrase query to ensure that fragments of the reference are matched in order

with this analysis chain for reference  `TR000002_1_2020` we get the tokens `["2", "1", "2020" ]`. So it will matches the queries `["TR000002_1_2020", "TR000002 1 2020", "2_1_2020", "1_2020"]`, but it will not match `3_1_2020` or `2_2_2020`.

Here is an example of mapping and analysis. It's not in Nest but I think you will be able to make the translation.

```
PUT pattern_split_demo
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "replace_char_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "^TR0*",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "split_tokenizer": {
          "type": "simple_pattern_split",
          "pattern": "_"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "split_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "split_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "replace_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "split_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST pattern_split_demo/_analyze
{
  "text": "TR000002_1_2020",
  "analyzer": "split_analyzer"
} => ["2", "1", "2020"]

POST pattern_split_demo/_doc?refresh=true
{
  "content": "TR000002_1_2020"
}

POST pattern_split_demo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "content": "TR000002_1_2020"
    }
  }
}
```